# How to search certain column title with a certain name and save it to new path

Tags: python, pandas, path, append, openpyxl

I am trying to search for anything that starts with "customers" in an excel file and save it to a new file path.

For example: A1 has :customer_id, B1 has:store_location C1 has: customer_purchase, I just want to save customer_id and customer_purchase to a new path.

so far this is what I have tried. Besides that, I don't know how to approach this.

```
customer_data=[]

if ws.cell=="customer":
   customer_data.append(ws.cell)
            
wb.save(new_path)
```

Comment: Or... Just let me know if this isn't doable

Comment: Probably doable but what is it you are trying to do? Find cells that include the text 'customer' and then copy/move the cell text/value to a new sheet/workbook or save value to a file?  What does 'new file path' mean? Please elaborate on what your attempting to achieve.

Comment: @moken I am trying to save everything containing the cell name "customer" and all the values under it from an existing workbook to a new workbook.

Comment: Why haven't you tried `ws.cell.value`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is relatively simple to do with pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel('customer_stuff.xlsx') #load the file
names = data.columns.tolist() #create a list of the columnnames
new_data = pd.DataFrame()

for name in names:
    if name.lower()[:len('customer')] == 'customer': #checks if the start of the string of length of 'customer' (8 chars) is 'customer'
        new_data[name] = data[name] #add the respective columns to the new data/file
        
new_data.to_excel('your//path.xlsx', index=False) #save the file
```

This is the simplest and most elegant way in my opinion.

Comment: I got the error 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: It shouldn't be a list... it should be a string, actually. It worked for me, let me quickly check.

Comment: Oh I messed up as I put names instead of name. But now it works!!! :) thank you so much!!!!

Comment: One more question, why did the new workbook printed another row of numbers(0-10) in column A??

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad, pandas does that automatically unless you specify .to_excel(path, index=False). I'll edit the answer quickly, you just have to add index=False after your path in the saving function at the end.